# Using reference lifetimes correctly in iterator

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I am trying to make an iterator out of some struct, `s1`, that has references within it with some lifetimes, say `'a` and `'b`. The iterator elements are new instances of the same struct type holding the same references. When I try to do this, the iterator elements appear to become subject to the lifetime of `s1` instead of just `'a` and `'b`.

An example for clarity:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MyStruct<'a, 'b> {
    num: i32,
    ref1: &'a i32,
    ref2: &'b i32,
}

impl<'a, 'b> MyStruct<'a, 'b> {
    pub fn with_next_nums(&self, n: i32) -> impl Iterator<Item=MyStruct> {
        (1..=n).map(|i| MyStruct { num: self.num + i, ref1: self.ref1, ref2: self.ref2 })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let i1 = 1;
    let i2 = 2;
    let s1 = MyStruct{ num: 0, ref1: &i1, ref2: &i2 };
    let s_next: Vec<_> = s1.with_next_nums(3).collect();
    drop(s1);  // commenting this line the program compiles
    println!("{:?}", s_next);
}
```

The error I get is:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `s1` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:19:10
   |
18 |     let s_next: Vec<_> = s1.with_next_nums(3).collect();
   |                          -------------------- borrow of `s1` occurs here
19 |     drop(s1);  // commenting this line the program compiles
   |          ^^ move out of `s1` occurs here
20 |     println!("{:?}", s_next);
   |                      ------ borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0505`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

So, because I am dropping `s1`, Rust assumes the elements of `s_next` will become invalid, even though `s_next` only holds references to `i1` and `i2`.

I suppose it is a matter of lifetime annotation, but I don't know how to fix it. If I were just producing a single struct out of `s1`, then I could annotate the return type like `MyStruct<'a, 'b>` and it would work, but just using `impl Iterator<Item=MyStruct<'a, 'b>>` as a return type does not solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your version is that because of the [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html) rules, since you didn't specify the lifetimes for `'a` and `'b` in the returned `MyStruct`, the compiler assumes they have the same lifetime as `self`. So, this as if you wrote:

```rust
pub fn with_next_nums<'c>(&'c self, n: i32) -> impl Iterator<Item = MyStruct<'c, 'c>>
```

To fix that you need to explicitly declare the lifetimes as `'a` and `'b`:

```rust
pub fn with_next_nums(&self, n: i32) -> impl Iterator<Item = MyStruct<'a, 'b>>
```

Now there will be another error in the declaration of `with_next_nums()`, because it *does* borrow from `self` as the closure captures it. You can fix that by adding `'_`, as the compiler suggests, but then your iterator will borrow from `self`, so your code (that collects them into a `Vec`) will work, but similar code that does not `collect()` immediately will not:

```rust
fn main() {
    let i1 = 1;
    let i2 = 2;
    let s1 = MyStruct {
        num: 0,
        ref1: &i1,
        ref2: &i2,
    };
    // The iterator is still alive when we drop `s1`, but it borrows from it.
    let s_next = s1.with_next_nums(3);
    drop(s1);
    let s_next: Vec<_> = s_next.collect();
    println!("{:?}", s_next);
}
```

A better fix is to change the closure so it will only borrow the fields it needs and not `self`. You can do it like that:

```rust
pub fn with_next_nums(&self, n: i32) -> impl Iterator<Item = MyStruct<'a, 'b>> {
    let MyStruct { num, ref1, ref2 } = *self;
    (1..=n).map(move |i| MyStruct {
        num: num + i,
        ref1,
        ref2,
    })
}
```

Comment: In my original (non-example) problem I was only concerned with the result of `collect()`, but avoiding capturing `self` in the iterator is a very good point.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in this case you need to specify the lifetime of both the iterator elements and the iterator itself. If you just specify the lifetimes of the iterator elements (with `impl Iterator<Item=MyStruct<'a, 'b>>`), the compiler assumes you will deal with lifetimes by hand and will give up trying to automatically assign a lifetime to the iterator. However, it does need to have the lifetime of the struct, because it depends on it, so it will fail to compile. The compiler error will actually give you the fix in this case:

```
error[E0700]: hidden type for `impl Iterator<Item = MyStruct<'a, 'b>>` captures lifetime that does not appear in bounds
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
9  |     pub fn with_next_nums(&self, n: i32) -> impl Iterator<Item=MyStruct<'a, 'b>> {
   |                           ----- hidden type `Map<RangeInclusive<i32>, [closure@src/main.rs:10:21: 10:24]>` captures the anonymous lifetime defined here
10 |         (1..=n).map(|i| MyStruct { num: self.num + i, ref1: self.ref1, ref2: self.ref2 })
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
help: to declare that `impl Iterator<Item = MyStruct<'a, 'b>>` captures `'_`, you can add an explicit `'_` lifetime bound
   |
9  |     pub fn with_next_nums(&self, n: i32) -> impl Iterator<Item=MyStruct<'a, 'b>> + '_ {
   |                                                                                  ++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0700`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

So, you just need to also add that `+ '_` to the return type to solve the issue:

```rust
impl<'a, 'b> MyStruct<'a, 'b> {
    pub fn with_next_nums(&self, n: i32) -> impl Iterator<Item=MyStruct<'a, 'b>> + '_ {
        (1..=n).map(|i| MyStruct { num: self.num + i, ref1: self.ref1, ref2: self.ref2 })
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that, since Rust's 2021 edition, it became mandatory to write the lifetime parameters, even if it means explicitly asking the compiler to figure them out on its own (with `'_`).